# How do you use the ActiveX RDP Client in MFC C++ Application?

Tags: winapi, com, activex, rdp

I can't seem to find a working example of how you're supposed to use the ActiveX RDP client.  I found [Using the Remote Desktop ActiveX control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/using-remote-desktop-web-connection) but it doesn't explain how it's to be used.  I was able to get a connection but since most of the methods return `void`, how do you do things like get any error codes, or test that connection was successful, detect the disconnect, etc?

What I used to get it working with no error checking is:

```
CMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings8 advancedSettings = m_ocx.get_AdvancedSettings6();

m_ocx.put_Server (L"192.168.1.2"); // ip processor
m_ocx.put_UserName (L"user"); // handler username
m_ocx.put_Domain(L"pc1");
m_ocx.put_DesktopHeight (768); // Resolution
m_ocx.put_DesktopWidth (1024); // Resolution
advancedSettings.put_SmartSizing (TRUE); // The size of the controlScalingThe Remote Desktop
advancedSettings.put_AuthenticationLevel(2);
advancedSettings.put_EnableCredSspSupport(TRUE);
m_ocx.put_ColorDepth(32);
m_ocx.put_DisconnectedText(_T("Disconnected"));
m_ocx.put_ConnectingText (_T ( "Please wait ...")); // display text in the interface connection
m_ocx.Connect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this document [ActiveX Control Containers: Handling Events from an ActiveX Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/activex-control-containers-handling-events-from-an-activex-control?view=msvc-170), use `BEGIN_EVENTSINK_MAP` to get the RDP control message. The event ID is in the header file of the [RDP class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/mstscax#methods)(CMSTSCAX1.h), here is my test code for your reference.

```
//use DECLARE_EVENTSINK_MAP() in CMFCRDPTestDlg.h

BEGIN_EVENTSINK_MAP(CMFCRDPTestDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_EVENT(CMFCRDPTestDlg, IDC_MSTSCAX1, 1, CMFCRDPTestDlg::OnConnectingMstscax1, VTS_NONE)
    ON_EVENT(CMFCRDPTestDlg, IDC_MSTSCAX1, 2, CMFCRDPTestDlg::OnConnectedMstscax1, VTS_NONE)
    ON_EVENT(CMFCRDPTestDlg, IDC_MSTSCAX1, 3, CMFCRDPTestDlg::OnLoginCompleteMstscax1, VTS_NONE)
    ON_EVENT(CMFCRDPTestDlg, IDC_MSTSCAX1, 4, CMFCRDPTestDlg::OnDisconnectedMstscax1, VTS_I4)
    ON_EVENT(CMFCRDPTestDlg, IDC_MSTSCAX1, 22, CMFCRDPTestDlg::OnLogonErrorMstscax1, VTS_I4)
END_EVENTSINK_MAP()

void CMFCRDPTestDlg::OnConnectingMstscax1()
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Connecting"));
}
```

Comment: That link was great, I was able to add through the wizard.  One thing you mentioned is the event ID is in the header file, but I don't understand what you mean by the event ID, I didn't see anything in that file.  Also where did the wizard get the `dispid` for the `ON_EVENT` line?

Comment: After adding the RDP control you can see `dispid` in the header file of the RDP wrapper class. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPRia.png

Comment: I see however the `CMSTSCAX1.h` file it generated for me doesn't have any of the `OnXXX` functions, just a lot of the `put_`, `get_`, `connect`, `disconnect` items so I couldn't see them.

Comment: Here are the steps I took to add the control. https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7sBD.gif

Comment: That was a lot easier than me messing around with the toolbox, which I added the "Microsoft Terminal Services Client Control - version 1" - which seemed to use the GUID for a newer version.   Is there a description of the difference on what the "redistributable" version are for?  I would expect it to use the installed copy in Windows already (required) so I wouldn't distribute anything.

Comment: Were you using Win10 or Win11 or another version of Windows.  I'm on Win10 x64 Pro, I still only get a partial list created.   There are other items I need access to like `put_RedirectDynamicDrives()` but it doesn't create it.

Comment: I tested it on Windows 11 Pro 22H2 22621.1413 with Visual Studio 2022 Windows SDK 10.0.22621.0.

Comment: I tried it on 22H2 22621.1702 but get same thing as before, after the enum's you get the `// IMsRdpClient10` and then the limited set of `get_` and `put_`  not the extra stuff you got.  I guess what I really need is in the `IMsRdpClientNonScriptable3` interface.

Comment: Do you see the same issue as I do with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76429262/rdp-activex-imsrdpclient10geterrordescription-always-returns-an-internal-erro

Answer (score 1):

To extend the answer by Junjie Zhu, after adding the ActiveX control there is a .tlh file created that defines all the interfaces.  To access the additional interfaces such as `IMsRdpClientNonScriptable3` you can do the following:

```
// get pointer to activex control (do not release() the pointer)
IUnknown* punknown= m_RDPClient.GetControlUnknown();
// query for the interface we want
CComQIPtr<IMsRdpClientNonScriptable3> pnonscriptable = punknown;
// use interface if it was found
if (pnonscriptable) {

}
```