# Connecting to RDP Using ActiveX control and Redirecting Printers results in Debug output of Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function

Tags: winapi, com, activex, rdp

Just wonder if this is a known issue when connecting to RDP using ActiveX control with Printer redirection enabled you get a bunch of: `Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.` messages having to do with `wcsicmp()` though `winspool.dll`.  I was on Win10 x64 connecting to Win7 x64 on VirtualBox.

Doesn't seem to hurt anything just had me worried I was doing something wrong?

TIA!!

Comment: When a C Runtime Library function detects an invalid parameter, it captures some information about the error, and then calls a macro that wraps an invalid parameter handler dispatch function. Which will be one of `_invalid_parameter`, `_invalid_parameter_noinfo`, or `_invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn`. Please provide a sample to help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: If you create the program as he did at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76369665/how-do-you-use-the-activex-rdp-client-in-mfc-c-application and simply connect (put_server(), connect()) with printer redirection you should see it in the debug output window.