# RDP ActiveX IMsRdpClient10::GetErrorDescription always returns "An internal error has occurred"

Tags: winapi, com, activex, rdp

I have an event handler for disconnect of an RDP ActiveX control in an MFC application.  In that handler I attempt to get the disconnect description via `GetErrorDescription()` however the string it returns is always **An internal error has occurred** even when the parameter matches the correct value (like user disconnect) as found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37870.remote-desktop-client-troubleshooting-disconnect-codes-and-reasons.aspx)

```
void CRDPView::OnDisconnectedMstscax1(long discReason)
{
    CString strreason;
    strreason=m_RDP.GetErrorDescription(discReason, m_RDP.get_ExtendedDisconnectReason());
    //...
}
```

I also tried just setting the extended reason to 0, and even hard coded `2,0` but same thing.

This is how Visual Studio setup the ActiveX Control for that function:

```
CString GetErrorDescription(unsigned long disconnectReason, unsigned long ExtendedDisconnectReason)
    {
        CString result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_UI4 VTS_UI4;
        InvokeHelper(0x1F7, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BSTR, (void*)&result, parms, disconnectReason, ExtendedDisconnectReason);
        return result;
    }
```

Any ideas?

FWIW, I use Win10x64 Pro and the powershell script does the same thing.

TIA!!

Comment: Well it looks like it may be that items 1, 2 return that and you have to create your own string for them?